# How much battery power is enough?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I want to download the latest system updates and some games, but when I try to do so, my 3DS tells me to connect to AC power and when it had sufficient power it will download the updates or games.

I am impatient. How much battery power is enough? I have it plugged in and charging.

Comment: I think I've done an update at half power?  I suspect it would depend on the update; bigger ones require more due to time to download and install.

Comment: Is it actually blocking you from continuing the update if you don't plug it in? Or can you just press A through the "you should plug in" message and have it update anyway?

Comment: @toomai it doesn't let me update. Even plugged in, if battery isn't charged enough it will just kick me back to the home menu

Answer (score -1):

That's odd. For me, it will update in a matter of seconds (with average bandwidth), even on battery power. I *do* know that the 3DS won't allow you to update it if it is on low battery power (has the red light, not flashing). I would assume that games and big updates would be the same.

Comment: It's not that it won't let me at all on battery power/plugged in, it's that there is a threshold where it won't let me because the device isn't charged enough, and I am trying to figure out where that threshold is.